# Find for which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{(\ln(1+x))^{\alpha}}\,dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> Find for which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the integral $$\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{(\ln(1+x))^{\alpha}}\,dx$$ converges

So I know that for every $\alpha \leq 0 $ it converges because the function would be bounded.
But I'm not sure about $\alpha > 0$.

How do I approach this? An antiderivative doesn't seem very comfortable

Comment: Note that $\frac{x}{1+x}\le \log(1+x)\le x$ so that $$\frac1{x^\alpha}\le \frac{1}{\left(\log(1+x)\right)^\alpha}\le \frac{(1+x)^\alpha}{x^\alpha}$$So for $\alpha<1$, the integral converges; otherwise it diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Since $log(1+x) = x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$ we have that the integrand as $x$ approaches to $0$ has the same behaviour of $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$, which we know it's convergent for $\alpha < 1$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac{x}{1+x}\le \log(1+x)\le x$ so that $$\frac1{x^\alpha}\le \frac{1}{\left(\log(1+x)\right)^\alpha}\le \frac{(1+x)^\alpha}{x^\alpha}$$So for $\alpha<1$, the integral converges; otherwise it diverges.

Comment: sorry but i'm not sure i get it.
first, why is the note true?
second, assuming it is true, why does the right side converge only for $\alpha < 1$?

Comment: I proved that inequality with precalculus analysis [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263).  Once we have the bounds, we can see that when $x\to 0$ the integrand is bounded by something that is of order $\frac1{x^\alpha}$

Comment: @user11555739 Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.